# Is there a numerical calculation for black hole - neutron star merges?

Tags: black-holes, neutrinos, neutron-stars, numerical-method

I think it might be even a more frequent event as the black hole merges. It would be similar to the black hole merges in the gravitational wave spectrum, but it could have a very clear neutrino and optical signature, too.

This signature might be visible from the Earth, while the gravitational wave detectors didn't produce result until now.

Was it ever calculated? If yes, how the results look like?

Maybe were such events already detected?

Comment: On what grounds do you base your predictions? Do you have supporting evidence that could help to put this question in context?

Comment: @JimtheEnchanter It was only my naive intuition. But the focus is the numerical results, thus I removed this part from the question. I only ask, does a such simulation already exist, and how the results look alike.

Comment: This [relevant literature search](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/basic_connect?qsearch=BH+NS+merger&version=1) gives a clear answer to your first query (an obvious yes). The "results" depends on what you mean by "results" (i.e., what specifically you're looking for).

Comment: @KyleKanos On the result I understand a general image about what happens in this case. For example, in the case of the supernovas, there are very clear descriptions, what is happening in the staller core, how the neutrino and photon signatures of a such event looks out, etc. In the case of the black hole - neutron star merges I didn't find any similar.